# Which browser compatibility data is more accurate - caniuse.com or developer.mozilla.org?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, caniuse

I am confused about caniuse.com and developer.mozilla.org data. For example, [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/atob-btoa) reports that `atob` function is supported in Chrome Android since 90 version, but [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) reports that since 18 version.

Is this incorrect data on caniuse.com or am I misunderstanding something?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are collaborating in some ways

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/09/caniuse-and-mdn-compat-data-collaboration/